# Is there a function for directx 2d to calculate string width?

Tags: c++, fonts, 2d, directx

i been recently messing around with directx2d c++ and i was wondering if there is a function to calculate a text width from IDWriteTextFormat?

Comment: I did do drawtext before but now i replaced it with DrawTextlayout. I already do GetMetrics but it always return the width value no matter how long the text is.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by removing wrapping.

```
pLayout->SetWordWrapping(DWRITE_WORD_WRAPPING_NO_WRAP);
```